# Increasing the heap size on Eclipse-RAD

Tags: eclipse, ibm-rad

I'm trying to increase the heap size on my RAD installation. When I make the changes, Eclipse isn't starting.

Current configuration...

```
-startup
plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.0.101.R34x_v20081125.jar
-install
C:\Program Files\IBM\SDP
--launcher.library
plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.0.101.R34x_v20080731
-vm
jdk\jre\bin\j9vm\jvm.dll
-vmargs
-Xquickstart
-Xms128m
-Xmx1024m
-Xmnx64m
-Xgcpolicy:gencon
-Xscmx96m
-Xshareclasses:name=IBMSDP_%u
-Xnolinenumbers
-XX:MaxPermSize=128M
-Dcom.ibm.ws.management.event.max_polling_interval=1000
```

I have changed startup to 256m and max to 1536m. With that change, Eclipse won't even start and I get this error..[image: Eclipse startup error]

Can someone explain what this means and how I can properly increase the memory? Thanks!

Comment: What did the file's content look like originally?

Comment: @nitind.. "current configuration" is the content of eclipse.ini file.. I was trying to modify Xms and Xmx in that file..

Comment: Can you try a slightly lower number?

Comment: It seems that you have a 32-bit os. Can you try starting with Xmx1024 or less?

Answer (score 0):

It's not about Eclipse, the virtual machine itself refused to come up. Possible reasons are:

- The xmx range is limited by the physical and *available* memory. So closing other running applications increase the chance to run this JVM with the increased settings.
- Some of the other JVM configuration options might be in conflict with that increased memory setting. I would therefore try to remove the other -X... arguments, while fiddling with the -Xmx option. If that succeeds, reintroduce the other arguments one by one to see where the conflict occurs.

Answer (score 0):

I frankly don't know the real reason but.. I just read about it here http://www.strongback.us/2012/01/increasing-the-jvm-heap-for-rsa-rad-and-other-rational-or-eclipse-products

Here is the excerpt from above link.

> You also MUST update the line
>
> **-vm ‘install directory’jdkjrebinj9vmjvm.dll** to
>   **-vm ‘install directory’jdkjrebinjavaw.exe**
>
> Otherwise, it will not respect the variables and **WILL crash your
>   Eclipse instance**.

PS: This solution or problem I've not experienced/tested myself.

Thanks,
Sameer Nafdey